# Transaction executed but 0 ETH sent

Tags: sendtransaction

When I try to send EHT using the below code, the transaction executes, but 0 EHT is sent:

```
const getEthereumContract = () => {
  // const provider = new ethers.provider.Web3Provider(ethereum);
  const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
  const signer = provider.getSigner();
  const transactionContract = new ethers.Contract(
    contractAddress,
    contractABI,
    signer
  );

  console.log({ provider, signer, transactionContract });

  return transactionContract;
};
  const sendTransaction = async () => {
    try {
      if (!ethereum) return alert("Please install metamsak");
      const { addressTo, amount, keyword, message } = formData;
      // getEthereumContract();
      const transactionContract = getEthereumContract();
      // const parsedAmount = ethers.utils.parseEther(amount);

      const parsedAmount = ethers.parseEther(amount);
      console.log(
        " ~ file: TransactionContext.jsx:71 ~ sendTransaction ~ amount:",
        amount
      );

      await ethereum.request({
        method: "eth_sendTransaction",
        params: [
          {
            from: currentAccount,
            to: addressTo,
            gas: "0x5208",
            value: parsedAmount._hex,
          },
        ],
      });
```

I see the follwing error in the browser console:

```
Error: contract runner does not support sending transactions (operation="sendTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.6.0)
    at makeError (errors.ts:677:21)
    at assert (errors.ts:694:25)
    at send (contract.ts:288:9)
    at Proxy.addToBlockchain (contract.ts:330:22)
    at sendTransaction (TransactionContext.jsx:88:57)
TransactionContext.jsx:104 Uncaught (in promise) Error: No ethereum objsct.
    at sendTransaction (TransactionContext.jsx:104:13)
```

Comment: Can you fix your code formatting please.

Answer (score 1):

In ethers v6, `provider.getSigner();` returns a promise (i don't really know why, that's confusing, unnecessary and would only lead to that kind of errors) . You're trying to use a promise as your signer. Add an await. Also, i formatted your code for you. Next time you ask a question, make sure to surround your code blocks by 3 backticks ( ``` ) before and after.

```
like this
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to call a function in your contract you should do;

```
const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum); 
const signer = provider.getSigner(); 
const transactionContract = new ethers.Contract( contractAddress, contractABI, signer );

await transactionContract.method(args, {value:12345})
```

method is to be replace by the method you want to call.

even if you want to send a raw transaction, you still have to work with a wallet or a provider.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question